# How to bit-shift integers past 31 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, binary, integer, bit-manipulation

In ECMA5 it says that the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, so in that case, the max safe integer is 2^31-1, or 2147483647.

However, the max safe integer otherwise is [2^53 - 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

For my program, I need to potentially deal with integers between 2^32 and 2^53.

So, my question:

Currently in my code I do something like this:

```
value |= (byte & 127) << (7 * i);
```

This doesn't work with `i` past 4 because it will be over the max shift range of 31.

So is the only alternative doing something like.. this? (still working on it)

```
value += (byte & 127) * Math.pow(10, i * 7);
```

Not completely correct but close enough to the point.. basically having to simulate ORing to a bitshift to get around the JavaScript restriction of 31 shift limits.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks, the `function lshift(num, bits) { return num * Math.pow(2,bits); }` did the trick.